# GemRequireError autoprefixer-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, autoprefixer

I am using autoprefixer in my ruby (2.2.2) on rails (4.2.3) application but there seems to be a GemRequireError and I can't figure out why or how to go about fixing it... can anyone give me some pointers?

I run bundle and it installs autoprefixer-rails 6.3.3.1 without a problem but when I try running the web using `rails s` I get an error.

The error:

```
user@ubuntu:~/development/myweb$ rails s
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'autoprefixer-rails'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
    from /home/user/development/myweb-web/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@myweb/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@myweb/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@myweb/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@myweb/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@myweb/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@myweb/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

My /home/user/development/myweb-web/config/application.rb:7

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
```

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'
gem 'activerecord-postgis-adapter'

# usage https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 3.4'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails', '~> 0.4.6'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

# security
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem "omniauth-islykill"
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"

gem 'paperclip-meta'
gem 'photoswipe-rails'

gem "autoprefixer-rails"

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails'
    gem 'coffee-rails'

    # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
    # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development, :test do
    gem 'rails-perftest'
    gem 'ruby-prof'
    gem 'capybara'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why but I ran `gem pristine --all` and the problem is gone. So, I guess there was some caching issue, creating some conflict or ambiguity with the *autoprefixer-rails*, but not the gem itself.

Answer (score 0):

In my project - I just change a row in Gemfile.lock:
from hashie (3.5.2) to hashie (3.4.6)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take some time to read how to write a good answer. read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/338114) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This should be posted as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I updated therubyracer to 0.12.3 for Ruby 2.4 compatibility

`bundle update therubyracer`